# When does boundedness imply totally boundedness in a metric space

Tags: general-topology

For a subset of a metric space, quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Metric_space):

> Total boundedness implies boundedness.
>   For subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ the two are
>   equivalent.

I was wondering what are some more general conditions for a metric space than being $\mathbb{R}^n$, so that boundedness can imply totally boundedness?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Compactness certainly does the trick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A metric space is totally bounded if and only if its completion is compact.  A subset of a complete metric space is totally bounded if and only if its closure is compact.  A metric space $X$ has the property that its bounded subsets are totally bounded if and only if the completion of $X$ has the property that its closed and bounded subsets are compact, a property sometimes called the Heine-Borel property.

[Montel spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel_space) are examples of these.

[Here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1987-100-03/S0002-9939-1987-0891165-X/)'s an open access article by Williamson and Janos you may find interesting.  For example, Theorem 1 (which they credit to a 1937 paper of Vaughan) says that a metrizable, $\sigma$-compact, locally compact topological space has a compatible metric with the Heine-Borel property.