# Sets where Heine-Borel theorem works

Tags: metric-spaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there more general spaces than Euclidean spaces to have the Heine–Borel property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104777/are-there-more-general-spaces-than-euclidean-spaces-to-have-the-heineborel-prop)

By Heine-Borel theorem, a closed and bounded subset of the Euclidean space is compact. If we analyze the proof, the only characteristic of Euclidean space that we need is: every bounded subset is contained in a compact subset. Is there a special name this kind of sets?

Comment: I think HB and this property are equivalent and hence I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Alex How can something that asks for a name and that asks you some examples be duplicates?

Comment: @KannappanSampath The question and answers answer the OP's question fully IMHO.

Comment: I think OP should clarify if (s)he wants to know the name of those spaces in which every bounded set is contained in a compact set or just a list of Heine Borel spaces! Please respond.

Answer (score 0):

This proves that HB is equivalent to the fact that every bounded subset is a subset of a compact set. Clearly, I am doing it on a metric space, only then this makes sense. As pointed out OP seems to understand this equivalence and hence is irrelevant.

---

**Heine-Borel Property:**

A metric space $(X, d)$ is said to be *Heine-Borel* if any closed and 
bounded subset of it is compact.

> You'd like to know the name of those spaces in which a bounded set is contained in a compact set (BIC).
>
> We claim that this property is equivalent to the Heine-Borel (HB) Property.
>
> - $(BIC\implies HB)$  Suppose a space $X$ is $BIC$. Let $B$ bounded subset of $X$. Because $X$ is $BIC$, $B \subseteq K$ where $K$ is compact. If $B$ is also closed, you have closed subset of a compact set which is compact. Hence the space is $HB$.
> - $(HB \implies BIC)$ Let $B$ bounded subset of $X$ that has $HB$. *We need to find a compact subset $K$ such that $B \subseteq K$*. Then the closure, $\bar B$ is closed and bounded, hence compact, because of $HB$ property and note that $B \subseteq \bar B$. Hence, $X$ is $BIC$.

So, **we can as well call these Heine-Borel spaces.**

*In fact, another characterisation of Heine Borel spaces is that, bounded sets are also totally bounded.*

Comment: You really need to specify that you’re talking about metric spaces, so that *bounded* is meaningful. Also, in the second half of the argument you seem to think that if $B$ is not closed, it must be open, which isn’t true. You might as well just go directly to $\operatorname{cl}B$ in the first place and not split the argument into cases. But I suspect that the whole answer is superfluous: according to the question, joh already understands this equivalence.

Comment: @Brian Doh. I am sorry then. This answer is irrelevant. :-(

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have made it CW because it may be of some help to other users, sometime later.