# Is it necessary to have a normed space for the Heine-Borel-Property to hold?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

The Heine-Borel-Property says:

A subset M is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

It is well known that the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ has this property. In a narrower sense I found the following.

A normed space $X$ is finite-dimensional iff it obeys the Heine-Borel-Property.

I was wondering if the property of the space $X$ to have a norm or a metric is necessary. In the proofs I found they are all based on balls, convergence and other notions where norms or metrics are involved. But in the statement of the H-B-Property, all concepts could be defined without a reference to a norm or a metric. For example, let $K$ be a complete, ordered field (like $\mathbb{R}$), then we could define the sets $(a,b) := \{ x : a < x < b \}$ and consider the topology $\tau$ generated by the collection of all such sets. So compactness could be defined as usual by requiring a compact set to have a finite open-cover, boundedness of a set $M$ could be defined as existence of a set $(a,b)$ with $M \subseteq (a,b)$ and closedness as $M$ is closed iff $K \setminus M$ is open, i.e. $K \setminus M \in \tau$. So now could the Heine-Borel-Property be proved for $K$? I don't find any proofs that doesn't use concepts like norm or metric (even the concept of limit could be defined without these concepts, like $x$ is limit point of set $M$ iff for every set $U$ with $x \in U$ if holds that $M \cap U \ne \emptyset$). Do you know any proofs that just use these basic notions?

Comment: You get the same topology if you add sets $(a,+\infty)$ and $(-\infty,b)$ to your basis of $\tau$. This changes the concept of boundedness and hence the validity of Heine-Borel. What makes your chosen basis special?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104777/are-there-more-general-spaces-than-euclidean-spaces-to-have-the-heineborel-prop) post may be of interest.

Answer (score 9):

The Schwartz space $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$ of test functions has the Heine-Borel property and is not metrizable.

Comment: How do you define bounded without a metric?

Comment: Here *bounded* should be taken to have its usual meaning in the context of topological vector spaces, of course; there is a Wikipedia page on that at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_%28topological_vector_space%29

Comment: Yeah. It is silly that spaces that have property X be called Y... :-/

Comment: I suppose your last comment was a response to my deleted comment pointing out that (barreled spaces) with this "Heine-Borel property" are called [Montel spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel_space). I think it makes sense to have the distinction because boundedness in the topological vector space sense cannot be detected by a *metric* -- otherwise this would force the space to be locally compact, hence finite-dimensional, which the space of distributions manifestly isn't.

Comment: s/distributions/test functions