# A question about Heine-Borel Theorem.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Im reading chapter2 of rudin's Principle of Mathematical analysis. Heine-Borel theorem is involved in this chapter,

> **$\mathbf{2.41}\,\,$ Theorem$\,\,\,$** *If a set $E$ in $R^k$ has one of the following three properties, then it has the other two:*
>
> $\quad\text{(a)}\,\,$ $E$ *is closed and bounded.*
>
> $\quad\text{(b)}\,\,$ $E$ *is compact.*
>
> $\quad\text{(c)}\,\,$ *Every infinite subset of $E$ has a limit point in $E$.*

I think that the k in $R^k$ should be finite, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Usually $k$ stands for a nonnegative integer when placed in "$\Bbb R^k$".

Comment: For generalizations, go to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104777/are-there-more-general-spaces-than-euclidean-spaces-to-have-the-heineborel-prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, k means a positive integer. FYI, in Rudin’s POMA, the symbol $R^k$ first appears in p.16.